# C Pointers & Struct

Tags: c

```
struct person {
  int age;
  char *name;
};
struct person first;
struct person *ptr;

first.age = 21;
char *fullname = "Max Smith";
first.name = fullname;
ptr = &first;

printf("age=%d, name=%s\n", first.age, ptr->name);
```

I'm trying to visualize what is taking place with the pointers.

1) We create a pointer called name which points to NULL initially.

2) We create an instance of person, called first.

3) We create a pointer that can only point to a "struct person".

4) We set the instance of first, to have an age of 21.

5) We create a pointer variable, that points to the string, "Max Smith".

6) We set first to the value that is held in the fullname variable.

7) Our ptr, pointer points to the values held in the first structure.

8) We print first's age, and we tell the ptr to point to whatever value is in the structure it is pointing to's name value.

Is my analysis correct?

Comment: 1) `name` is not necessarily `NULL`. It depends where and how each `person` is instantiated.

Comment: Until now it seems ok.

Comment: In your case, passing `ptr->name` is equivalent to pass `first.name`, if this is your question, as (*ptr) (i.e. ptr dereferenced) is "first", and `ptr->anything` is equivalent to `(*ptr).anything`

Comment: Well when it comes to the pointer, you could probably even say that `ptr->name` is equal to `*(ptr + name_offset)` which I assume will usually be `*(ptr + sizeof(int))` but that doesn't matter. Apart from the NULL default init (only true for static values), the analysis is correct. Actually the OP wording for `ptr->name` could be more appropriate than saying that it's equivalent to passing `first.name` which it isn't.

Comment: What is the reason for char *fullname = "Max Smith"; couldn't it not be a pointer variable?

Comment: No, pointers in C are also used to represent arrays where the pointer points to the first element. Character arrays (strings) are special cases also ended with null character (`'\0'`) that is secretely appended every time you write quotes, e.g. `"abc"` is `{ 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' }`. You can then see both `char* str` being addressed as `str[n]` or `*(str + n)` which are equal, offseting `n* sizeof(element)` from the pointer, accessing `n`th element. Notice the difference between `'c'` and `"c"` where `'c'` is a `char` and `"c"` is a `char*` pointing to an array of characters `{ 'c', '\0' }`.

Comment: Thank you, never knew the difference between single and double quote till today

Answer (score 0):

I took your program and built it, adding some code to generate the following memory map:

```
       Item        Address   00   01   02   03
       ----        -------   --   --   --   --
"Max Smith"       0x400bd0   4d   61   78   20    Max.
                  0x400bd4   53   6d   69   74    Smit
                  0x400bd8   68   00   61   67    h.ag

      first 0x7fff8c0ded10   15   00   00   00    ....
            0x7fff8c0ded14   ff   7f   00   00    ....
            0x7fff8c0ded18   d0   0b   40   00    ..@.
            0x7fff8c0ded1c   00   00   00   00    ....

  first.age 0x7fff8c0ded10   15   00   00   00    ....

 first.name 0x7fff8c0ded18   d0   0b   40   00    ..@.
            0x7fff8c0ded1c   00   00   00   00    ....

   fullname 0x7fff8c0ded00   d0   0b   40   00    ..@.
            0x7fff8c0ded04   00   00   00   00    ....

        ptr 0x7fff8c0ded08   10   ed   0d   8c    ....
            0x7fff8c0ded0c   ff   7f   00   00    ....

   ptr->age 0x7fff8c0ded10   15   00   00   00    ....

  ptr->name 0x7fff8c0ded18   d0   0b   40   00    ..@.
            0x7fff8c0ded1c   00   00   00   00    ....
```

Note that on my system, multi-byte values are stored in little-endian order, so you'll need to read the individual byte columns bottom-up and right-to-left.

So, going down the list:

1. The *string literal* `"Max Smith"` is stored as an array of `char` starting at address `0x400bd0`.  String literals are stored such that they are available over the lifetime of the program (often in a read-only section of the program image, which is why the address is so different relative to the other variables).
2. The struct instance `first` is stored starting at address `0x7fff8c0ded10`.  The instance takes up 16 bytes total.
3. The `first.age` expression evaluates to a 4-byte `int` starting at the same address as the struct instance and containing the integer value `21` (`15` in hex).
4. The `first.name` expression evaluates to an 8-byte `char *` starting at address `0x7fff8c0ded18` and containing the address of the string literal: `0x0000000000400bd0` (remember, read bottom-up and right-to-left).
5. To satsify alignment requirements, the compiler added 4 "padding" bytes between the `first` and `name` members, starting at address `0x7fff8c0ded14`.  Be aware that the size of a `struct` instance may be larger than the sum of the sizes of its members.  Note also that these padding bytes are not initialized and contain indeterminate values.
6. The variable `fullname` is an 8-byte `char *` starting at address `0x7fff8c0ded00`, and it also stores the starting address of the string literal.
7. The variable `ptr` is an 8-byte `struct person *`, and it stores the starting address of the variable `first`.
8. The expression `ptr->age` *dereferences* the `ptr` variable and accesses the `age` member of the pointed-to object.  In this case, it evaluates the same as `first.age`.
9. The expression `ptr->name` does the same thing as above; it accesses the `name` member of the `first` instance.

Some notes:

When you declare the `first` instance without an explicit initializer, the contents of both `age` and `name` are *indeterminate*; you cannot assume that `age` is initially 0 or that `name` is initially `NULL`.  If you want that guarantee, then you must either explicitly initialize the declaration:

```
struct person first = {0, NULL}; // or just {0}; partial initialization
                                 // will do the same thing
```

or declare `first` with static storage duration, either by adding the `static` keyword to the declaration or declaring the object at file scope (outside of `main` or any other function).